# Create a <ul> and fill it based on a passed array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've managed to generate a series of list-items based on one specified array within a matrix (i.e. an array within an array).

I would like to be able to pass a variable (representing an array) to a function so that it can spit out an unordered list filled with list-items based on the array passed into it.

**Problems:**

- The function only works with one array at a time
- It also produces commas in the markup (presumably, because it's converting the array to a string)

**The solution needs to:**

- assume that the unordered list does not exist in the DOM
- be able to accept different arrays passed into it (`options[0]`, `options[1]`, etc.)
- generate the list-items without commas

**JavaScript:**

```js
var options = [
        set0 = ['Option 1','Option 2'],
        set1 = ['First Option','Second Option','Third Option']
    ]

function makeUL(){
    var a = '<ul>',
        b = '</ul>',
        m = [];

    // Right now, this loop only works with one
    // explicitly specified array (options[0] aka 'set0')
    for (i = 0; i < options[0].length; i += 1){
        m[i] = '<li>' + options[0][i] + '</li>';
    }

    document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = a + m + b;
}

// My goal is to be able to pass a variable
// here to utilize this function with different arrays
makeUL();
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sTLbj/2/)**

Answer (score 101, accepted):

First of all, don't create HTML elements by string concatenation. Use DOM manipulation. It's faster, cleaner, and less error-prone. This alone solves one of your problems. Then, just let it accept any array as an argument:

```
var options = [
        set0 = ['Option 1','Option 2'],
        set1 = ['First Option','Second Option','Third Option']
    ];

function makeUL(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }

    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;
}

// Add the contents of options[0] to #foo:
document.getElementById('foo').appendChild(makeUL(options[0]));
```

**[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/sTLbj/4/)** You might also want to note that `set0` and `set1` are leaking into the global scope; if you meant to create a sort of associative array, you should use an object:

```
var options = {
    set0: ['Option 1', 'Option 2'],
    set1: ['First Option', 'Second Option', 'Third Option']
};
```

And access them like so:

```
makeUL(options.set0);
```

Comment: Yeah, I've made sure to ignore scope just to be brief. When I stick this in my project, it'll be nested inside a function.

Comment: Also, nice touch with the associative array.

Comment: Nice solution, +1 for not using jQuery.

Comment: Why is this up voted more than the one liner . "<li>" + options.set0.join("</li><li>") + "</li>" ?

Comment: @SahibKhan: That interprets the elements of `options.set0` as HTML, which is usually not desirable. (Common source of XSS vulnerabilities. Also produces an empty element when the list is empty.)

Comment: This makes a lt of sense. Create an element and append it where you want

Answer (score 9):

What are disadvantages of the following solution? Seems to be faster and shorter.

```
var options = {
    set0: ['Option 1','Option 2'],
    set1: ['First Option','Second Option','Third Option']
};

var list = "<li>" + options.set0.join("</li><li>") + "</li>";
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = list;
```

Comment: There is a chance your options comes from an untrusted source like an API. In that case you are open to XSS

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, and what if data is from trusted source?

Answer (score -2):

You may also consider the following solution:

```
let sum = options.set0.concat(options.set1);
const codeHTML = '<ol>' + sum.reduce((html, item) => {
    return html + "<li>" + item + "</li>";
        }, "") + '</ol>';
document.querySelector("#list").innerHTML = codeHTML;
```