# Insert list elements into body tag when a programme is in excution by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I use a **mind map programme** that is developed by **Kenneth Kufluk**. The reason I use his programme is because I have a programme that requests the users to enter a word for the center node of a mind map. Then, my programme will ask the users whether they want to continue or not. If they want to continue, then the users will be asked to enter something for a child node of the mind map and this process will continue until the users don't want to enter.

Below is HTML code and a picture indicating the mind map generated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Kenneth Kufluk 2008/09/10 -->
  <title>js-mindmap demo - JavaScript Mindmap</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js-mindmap.css" />
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- UI, for draggable nodes -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Raphael for SVG support (won't work on android) -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael-min.js"></script>

  <!-- Mindmap -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js-mindmap.js"></script>

  <!-- Kick everything off -->
  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

    <body>
      <ul>
        <li><a>kenneth</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a>Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a>LinkedIn</a></li>
            <li><a>Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a>RSS Feed</a></li>
            <li><a> Feed</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul> 
    </body>
</html>
```

[Mind map generated by Kufluk's programme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scj3N.png)

After reading those codes, I think it should be easy to figure out that if you want to add a child node, then you just need a new `li` element.

So, now my question is that how can I add new `li` items typed by users. This is because before the programme runs, I will delete whatever exists in `body` tag in order to make sure irrelevant things will not appear in the mind map. However, when I tried the codes in [Create a <ul> and fill it based on a passed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128700/create-a-ul-and-fill-it-based-on-a-passed-array), the word I typed did not appear in the shape but it appeared in the top left corner instead as shown in picture below (The codes I wrote are pasted below too).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Kenneth Kufluk 2008/09/10 -->
  <title>js-mindmap demo - JavaScript Mindmap</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js-mindmap.css" />
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- UI, for draggable nodes -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Raphael for SVG support (won't work on android) -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael-min.js"></script>

  <!-- Mindmap -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js-mindmap.js"></script>

  <!-- Kick everything off -->
  <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script src="mindMapConstructor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="displayMindMap"></div>

    <script language= "javascript" type= "text/javascript">
        function generateMindMap()
        {
            var list = document.createElement('ul');

            var centerNode = document.createElement('li');

            var link = document.createElement('a');

            centerNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Kenneth'));

            list.appendChild(centerNode);

            return list;    
        }

        document.getElementById('displayMindMap').appendChild(generateMindMap());
    </script>


  <!-- <ul>
    <li><a>haha</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a>LinkedIn</a></li>
        <li><a>Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a>RSS Feed</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul> -->
</body>
</html>
```

[Word appears outside the shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOc38.png)

If there is anyone knows how to make the word typed appear in the red colour shape please at least gives me some hints on how to do it. Thanks very much.

PS: This is my college assignment and the programming languages I have learned are HTML and JavaScript only.

Comment: Maybe reading http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ helps.

Comment: `document.getElementById('displayMindMap').appendChild(generateMindMap());`  and  `onload="generateMindMap()"` , why 2 calls to `displayMindMap()`

Comment: @smartmeta Thanks for the link given and I will learn it when I have learned JQuery :)

Comment: @Ramanlfc Thanks for the gentle reminder and I have updated the codes.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the demo, script.js "kicks everything off". Essentially it grabs the data and builds the mindmap when the document is ready.

You are adding elements to the list, but the mindmap doesn't automatically pick up on this; it only grabs the information that is present at the time it is run.

After a quick look through the mindmap code I can see there are a few functions, in particular there is:

```
$.fn.addNode = function (parent, name, options) {
    var obj = this[0];
    var node = obj.nodes[obj.nodes.length] = new Node(obj, name, parent, options);
    console.log(obj.root);
    obj.root.animateToStatic();
    return node;
}
```

and

```
$.fn.addRootNode = function (name, opts) {
    var node = this[0].nodes[0] = new Node(this[0], name, null, opts);
    this[0].root = node;
    return node;
}
```

Hopefully that answers your question as to why it's not working for you. A bit more digging and you might just get this working.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not have any fundamental in JQuery. So, do you mind if you explain to me especially a line where there are 2 equal signs?