# Display content of [object HTMLUListElement] using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

I have a javascript function which generates a ul list based on an array being passed in using a similar approach to this - [Create a <ul> and fill it based on a passed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128700/create-a-ul-and-fill-it-based-on-a-passed-array)

However, when I do the following...

```
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = generateListFromArray(array);
```

All that gets printed is

```
[object HTMLUListElement]
```

Can anyone tell me how to print the contents into the div as HTML?

Comment: Instead return a html string from the function.

Comment: Return string from function    and finally it will be like that                                                                           document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "<ul><li>List1</li><li>List2</li><li>List3</li> </ul>"

Comment: It would be very helpful to know what the `id="list"` element is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're creating a proper UL element (`HTMLUListElement`), which is great. You can use that *directly* by simply appending it to your target:

```
document.getElementById("list").appendChild(generateListFromArray(array));
```

**If** the target already contains content you want to *replace* (rather than add to), you can clear the target element first:

```
var list = document.getElementById("list");     // Get the target element
list.innerHTML = "";                            // Remove previous content
list.appendChild(generateListFromArray(array)); // Append your generated UL
```

There's simply no reason, at all, to convert the element you created to markup first (by using `.innerHTML` or `.outerHTML` on the return value of `generateListFromArray`).

**If** `list` is also a `ul` and you want to **replace** it, you can do that with `insertBefore` and `removeChild`:

```
var list = document.getElementById("list");     // Get the target element
var parent = list.parentNode;                   // Get its parent
var newList = generateListFromArray(array);     // Get the new one
parent.insertBefore(
    newList,                                    // Insert the new list...
    list                                        // ...before the old one
);
parent.removeChild(list);                       // Remove the old
newList.id = "list";                            // Give the new list the ID the
                                                // old one had
```

Answer (score 3):

Either use `innerHTML` or `outerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = generateListFromArray(array).innerHTML;
```

Use the `innerHTML` if you already have the `list` as `<ul>`.

Answer (score 1):

`generateListFromArray` returns HTMLUListElement. The simplest solution is to write its [outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML):

```
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = generateListFromArray(array).outerHTML;
```

However, if `#list` element in HTML is already a `UL` then you don't want to have extra `<ul></ul>` (markup will be invalid). In this case you would need to use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

```
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = generateListFromArray(array).innerHTML;
```

Comment: Oops... Sorry dfsq! `:)`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sure. Thanks. `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I just realized later that `list` might imply that it's a UL, so updated the answer. Don't be so paranoid, man :)

Comment: @dfsq I know... I apologized sorry! `:(`

Answer (score 1):

You might like to use `appendChild()` method:

```
document.getElementById("list").appendChild(generateListFromArray(array)));
```

Comment: No, this is not what OP wants.

Comment: @dfsq yup got it from your answer.

Comment: But you can clean innerHTML before appending, then it should be similar more or less.