# Javascript - Unable to display UL, instead get [object HTMLUListElement]

Tags: javascript

I asked a question a day ago about getting the length of an array that was nested inside an array that was inside an object. Now that I am able to get the correct information to console, I am getting the following in place of where the text should be:

```
[object HTMLUListElement]
```

Here is the code I am working with (please keep in mind I have been scouring the forums for answers, so there may be some code that is left over from different recommendations that is useless):

```
var experience = document.getElementById('experience');
var entryDescriptions = document.createElement('ul');


for (i = 0; i < resumeData.experience.length; i++) {
    var experienceEntryDiv = document.createElement('div');
    experienceEntryDiv.className = "experienceEntryDiv";
    var entryTitle = '<h1>' + resumeData.experience[i].title + '</h1>';
    var entryOrganization = '<h2>' + resumeData.experience[i].organization + '</h2>';
    var entryYears = '<h1 class="text-right"><small>' + resumeData.experience[i].startYear + ' - ' + resumeData.experience[i].endYear + '</small></h1>';

    for (j = 0; j < resumeData.experience[i].descriptions.length; j++) {
        descriptionCounts = resumeData.experience[i].descriptions.length;
        console.log(descriptionCounts);
        var entryDescItem = document.createElement('li');
        entryDescItem.className = "entryDescItem";
        var entrydesc = document.createTextNode(resumeData.experience[i].descriptions[j]);
        entryDescItem.appendChild(entrydesc);
        entryDescriptions.appendChild(entryDescItem);
    }
    var entryHTML =
        '<div class="entry">' +
        '<div class="row">' +
        '<div class="col-md-9">' + entryTitle + entryOrganization + '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-3">' + entryYears + '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="row"><ul>' + entryDescriptions + '</ul><hr /></div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<br />';
    experienceEntryDiv.innerHTML = entryHTML;
    experience.appendChild(experienceEntryDiv);
}
```

Here is my data (there is more data, I am just showing an example):

```
var resumeData = {

    experience: [{
            title: 'Title',
            organization: 'Company Name',
            startYear: 2017,
            endYear: 2017,
            descriptions: [
                'Using code stuff',
                'Used more code stuff'
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'Title',
            organization: 'Company Name',
            startYear: 2017,
            endYear: 2017,
            descriptions: [
                'Using code stuff',
                'Used more code stuff'
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'Title',
            organization: 'Company Name',
            startYear: 2017,
            endYear: 2017,
            descriptions: [
                'Using code stuff',
                'Used more code stuff'
            ]
        },
        {
            title: 'Title',
            organization: 'Company Name',
            startYear: 2017,
            endYear: 2017,
            descriptions: [
                'Using code stuff',
                'Used more code stuff'
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Originally, I was trying to figure out how to get the length in the second FOR loop. That got worked out, but now when I pull up the page, I get the Title, Organization, start and end years, but for descriptions I get:

```
[object HTMLUListElement]
```

Thanks!

Comment: This simply means that you are accessing the right object, but you need to access some aspect of the object, like a property or nested element.

Comment: Can you identify in the code where that disconnect happens? I have tried scouring the forums for an answer, and I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: entryDescriptions is a DOM element (a UL), and you are concatenating it as if it were a string to entryHTML, so it gets transformed into the string `[object HTMLUListElement]`

Comment: Eey, I got late, but you got your answer :) I'm very happy for you. Remember in the future do this, ask separate question for different issues ;)

Comment: @DamianLattenero I will do, thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using either all dom node creation (like the first part of your code) or all string concatenation (like the second part).

A quick (and VERY DIRTY, imo) workaround, would be:

```
...<ul>'+entryDescriptions.innerHTML+'</ul>...
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed, but now the descriptions are being appended and not wiped on the new run of the loop. I appreciate the "dirty" method of getting it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You're concatenating (adding) a string with a DOM Object.

```
var entryHTML =
        '<div class="entry">' +
        '<div class="row">' +
        '<div class="col-md-9">' + entryTitle + entryOrganization + '</div>' +
        '<div class="col-md-3">' + entryYears + '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="row"><ul>' + entryDescriptions + '</ul><hr /></div>' + //<--HERE
        '</div>' +
        '<br />';
```

You can either pull the text out of the object using Javascript, or update the page with `entryHTML`, then use Javascript to append the object `entryDescriptions`

Comment: Can you show me what that would look like? I am appending the <ul> and </ul> because I wasn't sure how else to get `entryDescriptions` into a <ul> format.