# Wondering how to achieve something similar to *ngFor/ng-repeat in jquery or JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Is it possible to have a similar concept of `ngFor` or `ng-repeat` in jQuery or vanilla JS?

Want to do something similar but not in angular way.

```
<div *ngFor="let inputSearch of searchBoxCount" class="col-sm-12">
    <textarea name="{{inputSearch.name}}" id="{{inputSearch.name}}" rows="2" class="search-area-txt" attr.placeholder="{{placeholder}} {{inputSearch.name}}">
    </textarea>
</div>
```

maybe use with the `data=""` attribute, whichever make sense.

Comment: _but not in angular way_ yeah, why using something good when we can make it worse...

Comment: Its because I'm not doing it in angular otherwise I will do it in angular. I just want to take the concept and apply it in jquery/vanilla js instead.

Comment: you'd probably want to use a <template>, possibly a web component with <slot> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128700/create-a-ul-and-fill-it-based-on-a-passed-array

Answer (score 7):

If you want it in `javascript` you have to create elements dynamically in a loop. *ngFor and ngRepeat in angular are directives that contains template bindings that we can't have either in javascript or jquery. Once the directives encounters angular try to render the respective templates till the loop ends. Anyway, by javascript we can do like this.
If you want to append 6 `divs` to the `body` element with respective `id`, You have to do like below.

```
var array = ['first', 'second', 'third', .......so on];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
   var elem = document.createElement("div");
   elem.setAttribute('id', array[i]);
   document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

We can't do it as we did in Angular with ngFor.

Comment: is there a dryer way of assigning attributes rather than writing them in separate line?

Comment: Nvm found my way.

Answer (score 6):

```js
    const anArray = [
        { tittle: "One", body: "Example 1" },
        { tittle: "Two", body: "Example 2" }
    ]
    
    function ngForFunctionality() {
        let value = '';
        anArray.forEach((post) => {
            value += `<li>${post.tittle} - ${post.body}</li>`;
        });
        document.body.innerHTML = value;
    };
    
    ngForFunctionality();
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 4):

In JQuery, I'd do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="searchbox-container col-sm-12">        
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var textAreas = $.map(searchBoxCount, function(inputSearch) {
    return $("<textarea></textarea")
      .attr({
        name: inputSearch.name,
        id: inputSearch.name
        rows: "2",
        placeholder: placeholder + " " + inputSearch.name
      })
      .addClass("search-area-txt");
});

$('.searchbox-container').append(textAreas);
```

Comment: Oh right I see, though `inputSearch.name` is not showing anything.

Comment: it returns the index instead (0,1,2), when I `console.log(inputSearch)`

Comment: @MrNew: Sorry, my bad. I got the argument order mixed up. Try my edited code.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to get a similar ngFor by vanilla. But it's possible!

My implementation (You can make it better using more regex):

HTML code:

```html
   <ul id="my-list">
      <li *for="let contact of contactsList">
        <span class="material-icons">{{ contact.icon }}</span>
        <span>{{ contact.value }}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

JS code for implement `*for` like Angular's `*ngFor`:

```js
/**
 * (*for) cicle implementation
 * @param element the root element from HTML part where you want to apply (*for) cicle. This root element cannot to use (*for). Just children are allowed to use it.
 * @returns void
 */
function htmlFor(element) {
  return replace(element, element);
}

/**
 * Recursive function for map all descendants and replace (*for) cicles with repetitions where items from array will be applied on HTML.
 * @param rootElement The root element
 * @param el The mapped root and its children
 */
function replace(rootElement, el) {
  el.childNodes.forEach((childNode) => {
    if (childNode instanceof HTMLElement) {
      const child = childNode;
      if (child.hasAttribute('*for')) {
        const operation = child.getAttribute('*for');
        const itemsCommand = /let (.*) of (.*)/.exec(operation);
        if (itemsCommand?.length === 3) {
          const listName = itemsCommand[2];
          const itemName = itemsCommand[1];

          if (rootElement[listName] && Array.isArray(rootElement[listName])) {
            for (let item of rootElement[listName]) {
              const clone = child.cloneNode(true);
              clone.removeAttribute('*for');
              const htmlParts = clone.innerHTML.split('}}');
              htmlParts.forEach((part, i, parts) => {
                const position = part.indexOf('{{');

                if (position >= 0) {
                  const pathTovalue = part
                    .substring(position + 2)
                    .replace(/ /g, '');
                  const prefix = part.substring(0, position);

                  let finalValue = '';
                  let replaced = false;

                  if (pathTovalue.indexOf('.') >= 0) {
                    const byPatternSplitted = pathTovalue.split('.');
                    if (byPatternSplitted[0] === itemName) {
                      replaced = true;
                      for (const subpath of byPatternSplitted) {
                        finalValue = item[subpath];
                      }
                    }
                  } else {
                    if (pathTovalue === itemName) {
                      replaced = true;
                      finalValue = item;
                    }
                  }
                  parts[i] = prefix + finalValue;
                }

                return part;
              });

              clone.innerHTML = htmlParts.join('');

              el.append(clone);
            }
          }
        }
        el.removeChild(child);
      }
      replace(rootElement, child);
    }
  });
}
```

Finally, in your component code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const rootElement = document.getElementById('my-list');

  rootElement.contactsList = [
    {
      icon: 'icon-name',
      value: 'item value here',
    },
    ...
  ];

  htmlFor(rootElement);
});
```

Finished. You have a `*for` on your vanilla code.

If anyone wants to experiment a performance comparison of this `*for` with the Angular's `*ngFor`, please share it with me, as I'm curious.

Code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-qvg6rv?file=script.js)