# How to Dynamically Build a List in JavaScript and Display in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, appendchild

I'm playing around with web development and looking to test some dynamically generated content, specifically just listing in a Chrome Extension popup all of the links on a site page. I referenced a great resource [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128700/create-a-ul-and-fill-it-based-on-a-passed-array) but I was testing with an `output` tag versus a `ul` and the creation of `li` for that list to show on the page.

**popup.html**

```
<div>
  <h3>Page output</h3>
  <output id="outputkey3">pages go here</output>
</div>
```

**popup.js**

```
function (tabs) {
  var tab = tabs[0];
  var url = tab.url;
  if (url != null) {
      var host = new URL(url).hostname;
    ...

var outputKey3 = document.getElementById("outputKey3")
if (outputKey3 != null) {
  for(var i = document.links.length; i --> 0;) {
    if(document.links[i].hostname === host) {
      //urls.push(document.links[i].href);
      outputKey3.appendChild(document.links[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Even for a single link this does not seem to be working. Not sure if this is meant to be done with a list versus another element that does not format the data with a preceding number or •. What I'd really like to do is just show a list that looks like a new line of data for each index value, perhaps as a bunch of `p`'s.

Comment: Where are you defining the 'host' variable? Your code looks OK other than that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532236/how-to-access-the-webpage-dom-rather-than-the-extension-page-dom)

Comment: Updated to show assigning of `var host = new URL(url).hostname;`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of things going against you here in your code.

1. `host` is never defined. You probably mean `location.host`
2. You rarely want to compare a host to a hostname. One includes the port and one does not.
3. As a best practice, you'll want to use a cloned form of the array. This is because the list can change while you are computing.
4. `document.links` includes all links, including the ones you add. Yet another reason to copy the array before changing page contents.
5. `appendChild()` will attempt to move the `<a>` and this could break the rest of the page. You probably want to clone the element.
6. `<output>` may have semantics that are inhibiting the additions. It is intended for computed results and may only have [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content). Consider changing to a `<div>` if you don't want a `<ul>`.

**Suggestion using clone**

```
var outputKey3 = document.getElementById("outputKey3")
if (outputKey3 != null) {
  // Get new array of filtered links
  // Document.links is not an array, but can be used by Array.prototype
  let links = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.links, function(link) {
    return (link.hostname === location.hostname)
      && (link.parentElement !== outputKey3);
  });
  // For each link, change its value to a clone of it
  let newLinks = link.map(function(link) {
    return link.cloneNode();
  });
  // For each clone, add it to the list.
  newLinks.forEach(function(link) {
    outputKey3.appendChild(link);
  });
}
```

**If you must use a for loop:**

```
var outputKey3 = document.getElementById("outputKey3")
if (outputKey3 != null) {
  for(var i = document.links.length; i-- > 0;) {
    if((document.links[i].hostname === location.hostname)
    && (link.parentElement !== outputKey3)) {
      //urls.push(document.links[i].href);
      outputKey3.appendChild(document.links[i].cloneNode());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @wOxxOm :  Absolutely true, but until the OP provides additional info, this is the proscribed code fix. If (and probably when) the OP changes his/her post, then I'll change my answer accordingly.